# Flashforward moments

Tags: perception

I've heard someone describe having what he calls "flashforwards": Moments he lives through which he feels like he remembers from before - on some occasions in situations he definitely did not see before. Is there any hard evidence on this or a name for the phenomenon? Is this some elaborate kind of self-deception?

Answer (score 2):

[Déjà vu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu) seems to match what you describe.

There are various possible explanations though they are a bit difficult to test since you can't readily activate the feeling in a lab setting. One of them is the idea that in the process of encoding a memory of the event it is simultaneously and erroneously "recalled".